# Using topo to raster tool on temperature contours and getting error 010089?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, contour, anudem

I am using the Topo to Raster tool in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 on a global temperature contour shapefile and keep getting this error:

> ERROR 010089: C:\Users\workspace is not a supported feature type.
>   Failed to execute (TopoToRaster).

I just used this tool on a smaller contour file and it worked just fine. I have not changed any default parameters other than not enforcing the drainage.

Additionally, if anyone knows of a global sea surface temperature raster file that would eliminate my need for this tool.

Comment: Are you using the Topo to Raster tool from [ArcGIS Desktop 10.x](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/topo-to-raster.htm) or from [ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/topo-to-raster.htm)?  Either way what were the precise parameter values that you provided to it?

Comment: ArcGIS desktop and I used default parameters other than changing not enforcing the drainage